# Track what is being spoken in iOS 7 TTS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I want to track the number of utterances in queue for AVSpeechUtterance. So I have multiple strings that are going to be spoken in the order that I set them up to speak. Is there a way I can track which utterance number is being spoken?

So say I have 10 utterances in queue to be spoken. I want to be able to NSLog which one is being spoken. So it should NSLog the following: `Utterance 6 Being Spoken`. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` and its `speechSynthesizer:didStartSpeechUtterance:` method. Let's assume that you store `AVSpeechUtterance` objects in a `NSArray`named `utterances`:

```
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didStartSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance {
  NSUInteger utternanceNo = utterances indexOfObject:utterance];
  NSLog(@"Utterance %@ being spoken", @(utteranceNo));
}
```